# IOError 2032 happens sometimes

Tags: actionscript-3, urlloader, ioerror

My application loads 60 files at the same time. I mean I  create 60 loaders (in an array) and start all loadings in a loop, I don't wait for one to complete before I start the next.
I use a class that extends URLLoader to load xml, bin, png, mp3 and swf.

I log when users get a IOErrorEvent, and I see error 2032 happen sometimes, not always with the same file, and when I try again, the loading completes.

Do you know why I could have a random 2032 error with URLLoader ?

Edit : Is URLLoader appropriate to load many files at a time ? Should I better have an open connection, request all the files, then close the connection ?

Comment: Maybe You should limit load stack to 5-10 files ?

Comment: Regardless, you should set up a limit and load a new file only when another is finished, start with 5 and then keep increasing the total number of concurrently open files and see if there is a limit before you start getting the error.  It might be with any more than one file at a time, but this is worth knowing.

Comment: I thought browsers handle this. They seem to load only 4 or 5 files at a time, and block the rest, waiting for one file to complete. We can't rely on browsers ?

Comment: I tried to use Sound for mp3, URLLoader for xml/bin and Loader for png/swf, but still the same random 2032 errors.
I tried to load one file at a time and I still log some users have the same IOError...

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of improper handling of `Loader` Events and data associated with it.

You can try using:

[BulkLoader Class by Arthur Debert](http://www.stimuli.com.br/trane/2007/nov/25/loading-reloaded/)

they have done some reliable work in this regard.

Comment: I need to load Class from swf file. Does BulkLoader allow to do this ?

Comment: Mate I can't figure out much without looking at the code itself. Here Check this out:

http://doesflash.com/assetloader/